# Denormalization of predicted data in neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, normalization

In Neural Networks, the number of samples used for training data is 5000 and before the data is given for training it was normalized using the formula

```
     y - mean(y)
y' = -----------
      stdev(y)
```

Now I want to de-normalise the data after getting the predicted output. Generally for prediction a test data data is used which is 2000 samples. In order to de-normalize, following formula is used

```
y = y' * stdev(y) + mean(y)
```

This approach is taken from the following thread
[[How to denormalise (de-standardise) neural net predictions after normalising input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320090/how-to-denormalise-de-standardise-neural-net-predictions-after-normalising-inp][1])

Could anyone explain me how the same mean and standard deviation used in normalizing the training data(5000*2100) could be used in de-normalizing the predicted data as you know for prediction test data(2000*2100)  is used,both the counts are different.

Comment: Bad attitude -- but I *did* neglect to up-vote your question.  Sorry for that oversight.  Also, I just caught how my reminder looks: I'm the only answer on this question.  [blush]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The denormalization equation is simple algebra: it's the same equation as normalization, but solved for y instead of y'.  The function is to reverse the normalization process, recovering the "shape" of the original data; that's why you have to use the original stdev and mean.

Normalization is a process of shifting the data to center on 0 (using the mean), and then squeezing the distribution to a standard normal curve (for a new stdev of 1.0).  To return to the original shape, you have to un-shift and un-squeeze the *same* amounts as the original distribution.

Note that we expect the predicted data to have a mean of 0 and a stdev around 1.0 (with some change in variations due to the central tendency theorem).  Your worry is not silly: we do have a different population count for the stdev.